# Automatic Gmail labels based on sender

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-filters

Is there some way to make Gmail apply a label to incoming mail automatically based on the sender?  For instance if Bob is my client, and all contact I have with Bob is work-related, can I make Gmail automatically apply the label 'CLIENT' to all incoming messages from Bob?

I would also be interested in a similar feature based on the recipient email address because I use my Gmail to check several accounts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure. You need to create a filter.

```
Matches: from:(bob@example.com)
Do this: Apply label "CLIENT"

Matches: to:(my-alternate-email@example.net)
Do this: Apply label "non-work related"
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew that feature had to exist. Thanks!

Comment: You can find filters under "Mail Settings".

Answer (score 5):

Click on `create a filter` at the top. Enter the email address you want a label for and click next. There you can say what you want to do with such emails. Click `Apply the label:` and choose which label you want. Then click the `Create Filter` button.