# Add newsletters to Labels Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I subscribed to Stack Exchange newsletters and  receive 8-9 newsletters per week.

I want to add them to "Stackexchange" label. After reading this [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/automatic-labels-in-gmail) , I created a filter, but don't know how to filter these newsletters i.e. what to write in sender's email field.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the procedure for creating a filter.

1. open a message that you want to filter and label.
2. Click on the "More" pull-down button.
3. Select "Filter Messages like these.
4. It will then open up the create filter wizard with the From filled in
5. In the background you should be able to see all the conversations that will be flagged by this filter.
6. Modify the value in the wizard if any need to be adjusted to capture more or fewer messages.
7. On page 2 of the wizard you will specify the label to attach to the messages, you can also create a new label at this point.
8. You must select "Also apply this filter to X matching conversations" to get the filter to process all the previous messages that the filter would have caught.
9. Click Create Filter Button

Notes:

- You can tweak this filter to add other addresses, or to change the actions (Archive, Forward...).
- All filters are found via "Gear Button/Settings/Filters.
- Multiple filters can use the same label.

Answer (score 1):

To filter **Newsletters** from **StackExchange** you'd enter the following into the filter boxes:

> **From:** `stackexchange`
>
> **Subject:** `Newsletter`

The **from** field will look at the email address **or** the senders name (in this case both: (no-reply@***stackexchange***.com)

and the **Subject** field will look for any matching words in the subject line (eg: Web Applications Weekly ***Newsletter*** - Tuesday, June 5. 2012).

[image: Gmail Filter for Stack Exchange]

A filter setup like the above screenshot will label only the StackExchange **newsletters**, handy for if you want to make the newsletters skip the inbox, but want all other stack communication to stay in the inbox.