# Gmail accounts - more than one possible?

Tags: gmail-filters

I have a gmail account.  I am now needing to set up an account to be used by a group as I have taken on a volunteer position and wish to communicate with this group of 50 or more people without it coming in and out of my personal email.  Do I need to set up a separate account or can I set it up with filters and mailing lists so emails between people in this volunteer group/organization are separated or highlighted in some way in my inbox. The reason is I want to be able to deal with these communications in a timely manner and do not want to sort through everything in my inbox.  If labels can be automatically applied to inbox messages and sent messages based on filters such as email addresses then this might be the best answer for my issue (only I would need to know how to do that).  Thank you.

Comment: Also you can have more then one account and be signed into multiple accounts at the same time you can look that up here: [Sign in to multiple accounts at once](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1721977?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically assign labels by using filters here is a previous question:
[Automatic Gmail labels based on sender](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/automatic-labels-in-gmail)

Also Here is the direct link to the gmail help page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en

I would however advise creating a mailing list using google groups for communicating with multiple users like you want to. You can find out more about Google groups [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview)